# How to make a secure HTTP/2 connection to Ruby server with Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, ssl, httpserver, http2

The following server code makes an SSL connection with curl and Safari, but it does not work with Firefox or Chrome. Works on Safari after saving cert exception.

```
  server = TCPServer.new( 8080 )

  ctx = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new
  ctx.cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.open('lib/keys/server.crt'))
  ctx.key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.open('lib/keys/server.key'))

  ctx.ssl_version = :TLSv1_2
  ctx.options = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::DEFAULT_PARAMS[:options]
  ctx.ciphers = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::DEFAULT_PARAMS[:ciphers]

  server = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLServer.new(server, ctx)
```

I tried adding the certificate to Firefox and the Keychain (OSX), but I still get

> The webpage at https://localhost:8080/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
>
> ERR_SPDY_INADEQUATE_TRANSPORT_SECURITY

Googling suggests that there is an issue with the ciphers, but the following did not make a difference:

```
ctx.ciphers = 'AESGCM:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5'
ctx.ciphers = 'EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES'
ctx.ciphers = 'TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; ssl_ciphers EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5'
```

Commenting out `ctx.ciphers` did not help either.

On Firefox, the connection hangs. Did not find a good way of getting the error.

Using Chrome 53, Firefox 46 and OpenSSL 1.0.2j.

What could cause this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Chrome insists on using ephemeral ECDH key exchange for HTTP/2, and to get that to work you need to set [`tmp_ecdh_callback`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/SSL/SSLContext.html#tmp_ecdh_callback-attribute-method):

```
ctx.tmp_ecdh_callback = lambda do |*args|
  OpenSSL::PKey::EC.new 'prime256v1'
end
```

I’ve based this on the [example code from the Ruby http-2 gem](https://github.com/igrigorik/http-2/blob/bf4b930c19934521bb0ffcfa19486ff7e415ed55/example/server.rb), which I think is where you’ve got your code from too. Note that in that code it uses `lambda do |_args|`, (with the underscore but no `*`) and this causes problems because the number of args is wrong and `lambda` is strict about passing the right number, so you get errors. I’ve changed it back to the original `*args` here, it appears to have [been changed to fix Rubocop warnings](https://github.com/igrigorik/http-2/commit/48366f1d1aeeefe272ac9d00612813518278899c). As you seem to be active in that repo, you might want to change it to something like `|*_args|`.

Comment: It looks like this behaviour will change in future versions of Openssl and the Ruby bindings: https://github.com/ruby/openssl/commit/fcb9b4a6b5c6e30a99d9acb8c73e62c3c7559001

Comment: OMZ. I spent about a whole day trying to figure this out. And, I am using the same example code. I thought it was a problem with the ciphers. I had taken out this code because it was causing problems, and was just about to add it back in and see why it was failing.

Comment: @BSeven it took me a while to figure out what was going on too. The problem with using `lambda` was tricky—it was causing the callback to fail completely, but it wasn’t obvious why.

Comment: Works on Chrome, but on Firefox 49 it just hangs.

Comment: Well, I figured one thing out. Fix for Firefox: `ctx.alpn_protocols = ['h2']`.